# Mapping for elastic search Match query

Tags: elasticsearch

What are the mappings to be used for Match query to achieve below mentioned cases

- case insensitive search
- Numbers search
- special character search
- single character search

- i tried with wildcard but id does not support case insensitive
- tried match query with lowercase normalizer it does not support    special characters and single character search
- tried match query with ngram but it does not support    special characters and Number search.

```
PUT index_v14
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "skm_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "skm_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "skm_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol",
            "custom",
          ]
          "custom_token_chars": "/@[]-"
        }
      }
    }
  },
"mappings": {
  "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "skm_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search"
        },
}
```

```
GET index_v14/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title":{
        "query":"[watch]: hello/stars",
        "operator":"and"
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone help me with the mapping to support all the mentioned cases above whether its for type `text` or type `keyword` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which tokenizes input `string` in a format which satisfy all your need.

[ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html), and [Mapping charfilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) are few building blocks which you need in your custom analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer amit , can you help me with how to add `custom_token_chars` in ngram tokens

Comment: @Dineshkarthik would be great if you can first show what you have tried, and I can build on top of it..

Comment: Amit i added the mapping setting in question can you help me with how to add `custom_token_chars` in `token_chars`

Comment: added the `custom_token_chars` with multiple special characters in above code can you check whether it is correct

Comment: @Dineshkarthik, can you add few sample strings, sample documents with required search results to check it

Comment: added the search query and title mapping

Comment: Amit can you help with full analyser  setting for the use cases